# What is the grammar of the sentence "this is not some science fiction movie come to life."

Tags: tense

The sentence is:

> This is not some science fiction movie **come** to life.

Is this sentence grammatically right? If this sentence is right, please tell me what the grammatical rule about the word **come** is, why does it use form **come** rather than the others like **to come**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Come to life" is a past-participial clause modifying "movie", It has the same meaning as the relative clause "that has come to life".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The verb *come* has an irregular past participle, which is also *come*. It is being used in your example as a past participle.

Answer (score 12):

"[come to life](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/bring-sth-to-life-come-to-life)" refers to: "to make something more real or exciting, or to become more real or exciting."

"Come to life" is an [idiom](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/idiom), which is "a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words (e.g. over the moon, see the light )."

The sentence is grammatically correct and you can think about it as a short version of: "This is not some science fiction movie that has come to life."

Comment: Arguably we should understand it not as “…that has come to life” but rather as “…that *is* come to life”.  This ‘deponent’ usage of the participle is archaic, surviving in only a few such constructions.

Answer (score 4):

As an English person, this feels like US parlance (though we probably use the expression these days as well); especially with the "some *noun*" before it.  It is valid, grammatically speaking.

You can think of it a bit like this:

> this is not some science fiction movie *that has just* come to life

or, probably in the given context:

> this is not some science fiction movie *that has just* come to life [apropos of nothing]

hope that helps!

Comment: As a British English speaker in his 60s, the only thing that sounds American to me is the use of "movie" (BrE usage would be "film").