# Is the sentence "is not some ... movie" grammatical?

Tags: grammar

An ELL [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240142/109190) says

> This **is not** some science fiction movie come to life.

I am confused by this sentence.

"is" implies that an unexpected event happened, such as a robot with high intelligence has been made. The event is individual, so it's singular. I understand this part.

"some" with countable nouns usually indicates a few of something in plural form. However, that sentence uses a singular form "movie". I cannot understand this part.

Could someone please give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need a bit of more context there.

I think that the original poster may have taken that excerpt from this [tweet](https://twitter.com/Reuters/status/1237071904286048256) quoting the
declarations of an American polititian

> "This is not ebola, this is not SARS, **this is not some science fiction
>   movie come to life**. The hysteria here is way out of line with the
>   actuality and the facts"

**This** in your sentence does not represent a robot nor any sci-fi topic, the polititan is talking about the actual global coronavirus crisis. This crisis is not a (science-) **fiction** story, it's very real.

In this context the word **[some](https://www.lexico.com/definition/some)** means, according to the Oxford Dictionary

> Used to refer to someone or something that is unknown or **unspecified**

It's not a (unspecified) science-fiction movie what we're living right now.
He's not comparing our situation with a **specific** movie because it's not relevant at all for the rest of his declaration.

You can check more examples of that use of **some** in the linked reference.