# Why isn't the verb conjugated here?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence :

> It was a dream **come** true .

What's the grammatical rule used here ?

Is this sentence structure common ?
If so , could you please give me an example ?

Comment: You might find this post interesting: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/240142

Comment: @MichaelRybkin thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the grammar of the sentence "this is not some science fiction movie come to life."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/240142/what-is-the-grammar-of-the-sentence-this-is-not-some-science-fiction-movie-come) It's just that the past participle of ***come*** is actually ***come***. With a different verb, such as *It was a dream **wanted** by everyone*, you shouldn't have a problem seeing how the syntax works.

Comment: it does , and your example has made it even clearer to me , many thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The word *come* has the same form for infinitive and past participle.

Past participles can be used like post-positive adjectives, it's equivalent to saying "X that is Y'ed" or "X that has Y'ed."

> It was a dream come true = It was a dream that has come true.
>
> It was a dream destroyed completely = It was a dream that was destroyed completely.
>
> It was a dream driven insane = It was a dream that was driven insane.